# why does it say, TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Tags: python-2.7

why does it say, TypeError: expected a character buffer object?

```
import urllib
import re

myfile = open("C:\Users\Teli\Desktop\pro.txt", "w")

page = urllib.urlopen("http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm").read()

a = re.findall('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', page)

myfile.write(a)

myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.findall()` returns a list of matches, not a string. You have to get the string out of it:

```
import urllib
import re

with open(r'C:\Users\Teli\Desktop\pro.txt', 'w') as handle:
    page = urllib.urlopen('http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ip-address-01.htm').read()
    addresses = re.findall(r'(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', page)

    handle.write('\n'.join(addresses))
```